# What do you call a person who talks about their accomplishments only?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language, epithet-requests

What do you call a person who goes on and on about how great their accomplishments are?

Comment: A braggart and a bore.

Comment: What about *Braggadocious*

Comment: You could try to get the question reopened by some good editing, for example, a sample sentence, and reasons why you rejected the obvious choices.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best word for your situation would be **Boastful**:

> #### Boast
>
> - To praise oneself extravagantly in speech; speak of oneself with excessive pride.
>
> *"All Stacey does is boast about her accomplishments."*

([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/boast))

Answer (score -3):

- Arrogant
- Full of oneself
- Conceited
- Cocky

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. We appreciate answers which provide context, sources,  and explanation. Comments are strictly for the comment section below questions and answers. When you have enough reputation, you will be able to place comments. If you have any doubts about "How to write a good answer", please visit our [Help Page](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)